# Obter item da linha e coluna de uma tabela html dinâmica

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

Bom dia pessoal, montei uma tabela em html dinâmica com informações de uma table do SQL. Na seguinte estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Está tabela tem um campo de filtro das agências listadas código:

```js
    <script>
        function myBusca() {
 
            var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
            input = document.getElementById("myInput");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            table = document.getElementById("myTable");
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                if (td) {
                    if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        tr[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Preciso ao clicar no icon de cada linha obter o nome da agência e seu código e enviar para um campo TextBox estou tentando com o seguinte script:

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("cidade").value;
            document.getElementById("<%=txtCidadeAgencia.ClientID %>").value = x;
        }
    </script>
```

```html
<td style='vertical-align: middle;'>" +
 "<input id='cidade' name='cidade' " +
 "type='hidden' value='{0}'>" +
 "<a href= \"#\"" +
 "class=\"btn btn-default\" " +
 "onclick='myFunction()' data-toggle='modal' " +
 "data-target='#myModal' data-dismiss='modal'>" +
 "<i src=\"#\" class='fa fa-hand-pointer-o'></i></a>" +
 "</td></tr>"
```

Mas não consigo, imagino que tenho que pegar o index da linha para obter os campos da seleção.
Alguém poderia dar uma orientação para mim.

Obrigado.

Comment: Poderia atribuir um evento onclick no ícone, quando for disparado ele chama uma função do Javascript passando o texto para preencher o textbox.

Comment: Eu estou passando o evento onclick='myFunction()' no ícone dessa forma: 
<td style='vertical-align: middle;'>" +
                     "<input id='cidade' name='cidade' " +
                     "type='hidden' value='{0}'>" +
                     "<a href= \"#\"" +
                     "class=\"btn btn-default\" " +
                     "onclick='myFunction()' data-toggle='modal' " +
                     "data-target='#myModal' data-dismiss='modal'>" +
                     "<i src=\"#\" class='fa fa-hand-pointer-o'></i></a>" +
                     "</td></tr>"

Comment: Eu imaginei desta forma `onclick="myFunction('Texto Para Ser Exibido')"` e nessa função `myFunction(x)` recebe o `x` e seta `document.getElementById("<%=txtCidadeAgencia.ClientID %>").value = x;`.

Comment: Lembrando que é importante dar nomes significativos para as variáveis.

Comment: Valeu @LP. Gonçalves, cara estava explicito e eu não via! Estou mexendo mais agora com javascript, antigamente só webforms/aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução:

Código do icone:

```html
 html.AppendFormat(
                    "<td style='vertical-align: middle;'>" +
                    "<a href= \"#\"" +
                    "class=\"btn btn-default\" " +
                    "onclick='myFunction(\"{0}\")' data-toggle='modal' " +
                    "data-target='#myModal' data-dismiss='modal'>" +
                    "<i src=\"#\" class='fa fa-hand-pointer-o'></i></a>" +
                    "</td></tr>", item.CidadeAgencia);
```

Função para obter o item selecionado na tabela, e enviar para um campo TextBox:

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction(cidade) { 
           document.getElementById("<%=txtCidadeAgencia.ClientID %>").value = cidade;
        }
    </script>
```

Obrigado [LP. Gonçalves](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/43183/lp-gon%C3%A7alves)